# Serializing user groups as an array without keywords in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a Django project with the django_rest_framework. I am trying to create a serializer that returns a user with all the groups that he belongs to as a simple array.

For example:

```
{
   "username": "John Doe",
   "groups": "[Group1, Group2]"
}
```

My current configuration however returns the groups as objects and adds attribute names, so my previous example unfortunately returns as follows:

```
{
   "username": "John Doe",
   "groups": "[{"name":"Group1"},{"name":"Group2"}]"
}
```

Are you able to get the achieve the result that I want with the django_rest_framework? Here are my serializers:

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name',)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'groups')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'groups')

    def get_groups(self, obj):
        return [group.name for group in obj.groups]
```

Comment: obj.groups is a m2m field, it's better to convert it to a query_set: obj.groups.all()

Answer (score 0):

Try to override GroupSerializer's  `to_representation` method:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name',)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

Didn't test it, please check if this work.

Comment: didnt work out for me. still returned groups: Array(1) { 0 : 1 } in json response.